# Not booting ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot

I have used ubuntu 14.04 for sometime and it has always worked well for me. Now it won't boot. If I try to boot, it will show all the voltages, but then just hangs there.
If I press and keep down F9 after switching on, it allows me to select the hard drive with ubuntu on, and everything proceeds to boot up.

I have changed the battery, as suggested by my nephew, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct drive as the default boot medium in the BIOS set-up of your computer.

How you enter BIOS set-up and make the configuration change depends on the specific BIOS. Please consult your system manual which should contain instructions to that extent. If you still can't manage to make the change, I recommend that you open a new question with pictures (of the BIOS set-up screen etc.) over on [SuperUser](//superuser.com/) since BIOS lies outside of the control of Ubuntu and is borderline off topic here on Ask Ubuntu.